# Using animate package for gif that is not in root directory

Tags: animate, source, gif

I have converted the gif into a series of pdf files and now I want to use the animate package to embed pdf 'images', called exp_%d.pdf, into my LaTeX pdf. However, the source of the pdf files is located one folder deeper (in the folder 'gifs') than the .tex file I am trying to reach them from. How would I go about using these pdfs. For reference this is the LaTeX I am using now.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \animategraphics[height=1.4in,autoplay,controls,loop]{10}{gifs/exp_}{0}{280}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\graphicspath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate,graphicx}
\graphicspath{{gifs/}}

\begin{document}

    \animategraphics[height=1.4in,autoplay,controls,loop]{10}{exp_}{0}{280}

\end{document}
```